# Merge files using a common column

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have two files out of which I want to create a third which contains all the information.

file 1:

```
a 111 
b 222 
c 333 
d 666 
e 777
```

file 2:

```
111 x1  
222 x2
333 x3
444 x4 
555 x5 
666 x6 
777 x7 
888 x8
```

I would like to combine them as following:

```
111  x1  a
222  x2  b
333  x3  c
444  x4  0
555  x5  0
666  x6  d
777  x7  e
888  x8  0
```

Note:

The second column of file 1 is a subset of the first column of file 2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `join` command does almost what you need, if the files are sorted as in your samples:

```
join -12 -a2 file1 file2 -o2.1,2.2,1.1
```

You just need to add the zeroes to the lines with no match. You can use the `-e` switch for that:

```
join -12 -a2 file1 file2  -o2.1,2.2,1.1 -e0
```

Comment: if you add the `-e0` do not need perl :)

Comment: @LilloX: True, thanks. I tried but failed (typo).

Answer (score 13):

Using join:

```
join -1 1 -2 2 -a1 -e0 -o'0,1.2,2.1' file2 file1
```

The join command joins the lines of two files which share a common field of data.
In this case:
Join the file2 and the file1 using the field 1 ( `-1 1`) of the file2 and the field 2 ( `-2 2`) of the file1.

The output will be: "joined field, field 2 of file2, field 1 of file1" (`-o'0,1.2,2.1'`), if there is a missing field put 0 (`-e0`)

If one of the two files have more records then add them (in this case file2) (`-a1`)

Please refer to the manpage of the command join

Comment: Good. Could you add a bit of explanation?

Comment: Sure, Updated :)

Answer (score 5):

A little bit `awk` magic:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next}{if(a[$1]==""){a[$1]=0}; \
    printf "%s%s%s%s%s\n",$1,FS,$2,FS,a[$1]}' \
    file1 file2
```

or

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next}{if(a[$1]==""){a[$1]=0};
    print $1,$2,a[$1]}' file1 file2
```

---

*Output*

```
111 x1 a
222 x2 b
333 x3 c
444 x4 0
555 x5 0
666 x6 d
777 x7 e
888 x8 0
```

---

*Explanation*

- `FNR==NR{a[$2]=$1;next}`

  Runs over `file1` (`FNR==NR`) and creates a key-value structure. The key is the second column (`$2`) of `file1`, the value is the first column (`$1`) of `file1`
- `{if(a[$1]==""){a[$1]=0};print $1,$2,a[$1]}`

  Runs over `file2` and

  - `if(a[$1]==""){a[$1]=0}`

    If the key in the first column (`$1`) in `file2` doesn't exist in `file1`, we need a `0`
  - `print $1,$2,a[$1]`

    Print (using `print`) the first and the second column of `file2` and the value of the key-value structure with the key of the first column (`$1`) of `file2`

    or
  - `printf "%s%s%s%s%s\n",$1,FS,$2,FS,a[$1]}'`

    Print (using `printf`) the first and the second column of `file2` and the value of the key-value structure with the key of the first column (`$1`) of `file2`.

    - `FS` is the separator between the columns, taken from the input file
    - `"%s%s%s%s%s\n"`

      is the formatting for the output

      - `%s` - String
      - `\n` – Newline

Comment: Could you explain the code?

Comment: Sure, answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Using [q](https://github.com/harelba/q):

```
$ q "select f2.c1, f2.c2, ifnull(f1.c1,0) from file_2.txt f2 LEFT JOIN file_1.txt f1 on f1.c2 = f2.c1 "
111 x1 a
222 x2 b
333 x3 c
444 x4 0
555 x5 0
666 x6 d
777 x7 e
888 x8 0
```

It may be more readable this way sometimes.

Comment: For anyone wondering, `q` is in the package `python3-q-text-as-data` (Python 3) and in the package `python-q-text-as-data` (Python 2).

Comment: Thanks, but where can I get this `q` package? I don't seem to be able to install either `python-q-text-as-data` or `python3-q-text-as-data`. "E: Unable to locate package python3-q-text-as-data". My system already has installed `python`, `python2.7`, `python3`, and `python3.4`.

Comment: Maybe the package is too new and is not available in your distribution release. You can clone it Github: https://github.com/harelba/q