# bash - merging 2 files using 2 common columns and add up the values of the 3rd column

Tags: bash, awk, split, merge

I am new to the use of the bash shell and all the unix commands. So I hope my question is not too stupid, I could not find anything in the previously asked questions to help me solving my problem.

I created a file that looks like this:

```
apple:::NN \t garden:::NN \t 5
garden:::NN \t great:::Adj \t 1
nice:::Adj \t a:::DT \t 2
etc
```

Now I have another file:

```
apple:::NN \t garden:::NN \t 15
house:::NN \t nice:::Adj \t 1
garden:::NN \t great:::Adj \t 5
etc
```

I need to combine the files, so the merged output file would look like this:

```
apple:::NN \t garden:::NN \t 20
garden:::NN \t great:::Adj \t 6
nice:::Adj \t a:::DT \t 2
house:::NN \t nice:::Adj \t 1
```

The problem is that the lines are not the same in both files, so I cannot iterate through the files line by line. I can split the lines of course, however I have to consider column 1 and column 2 as a unit to be able to add the numbers if column 1 and column 2 are the same in both files. Lines that are just found in 1 file have to go to the output file as they are.

I can do it manually using 'awk' or 'grep' but is it possible to also do that in a loop? If someone has a hint to solve the 'line' problem, that would help me a lot already!

The closest solution I could get to, is the following [Merge files using a common column](https://askubuntu.com/questions/707843/merge-files-using-a-common-column) However, I could not get the join command using 2 columns plus adding up the values of the 3rd column.

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: This is on-topic here, but I just want to mention that you may get a better answer at StackOverflow.com since it's more focused on programming.

Comment: Are the cells of the first and second columns all unique relative to their own column?

Comment: What do the ` \t ` sequences mean? are you trying to indicate that your data are tab-delimited?

Comment: @wjandrea no they are not. There are multiple lines in the column containing these words. It is just the combination of the 2 columns that is unique in each of the whole files.

Comment: @ steeldriver ja, that is what I was trying to indicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "classic" solution for this kind of thing uses an associative array in awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"; OFS=FS} {a[$1 FS $2] += $3;} END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' file1 file2
nice:::Adj      a:::DT  2
house:::NN      nice:::Adj      1
apple:::NN      garden:::NN     20
garden:::NN     great:::Adj     6
```

(note that the output order is not guaranteed). A similar algorithm can be implemented in `perl` using a hash.

A newer tool that you may wish to try out is [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) which allows grouping by fields and various mathematical operations on the results e.g.

```
$ cat file1 file2 | datamash -s groupby 1,2 sum 3 
apple:::NN      garden:::NN     20
garden:::NN     great:::Adj     6
house:::NN      nice:::Adj      1
nice:::Adj      a:::DT  2
```